# Clean way to write IF statements in python to skip on None?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I have a function where sometimes a parameter can be none, and I would like to compare that with another object. However, if I am trying to call an object property, my script will throw an exception on None, even if both objects are None (see example below).

```
def do_animals_make_same_sound(first_animal, second_animal):
    if first_animal.sound = second_animal.sound:
        print('Yes they do!')
```

But if both animals are None, it throws an exception when instead I want it to print('Yes they do!'), but it seems I have to write a really ugly If statement:

```
def do_animals_make_same_sound(first_animal, second_animal):
    if (first_animal is None and second_animal is None) or (first_animal is not None and first_animal.sound == second_animal.sound):
        print('Yes they do!')
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

following code is clearer IMHO:

```
def do_animals_make_same_sound(first_animal, second_animal):
    # early return if one of the two animals is missing, ensure both exist
    if not (first_animal and second_animal):
        return
    if first_animal.sound == second_animal.sound:
        print('Yes they do!')
```

ref: [Avoid Else, Return Early](http://blog.timoxley.com/post/47041269194/avoid-else-return-early)

Answer (score 0):

It's not great, but one approach can be to use `getattr` with a default, so `None` (and anything else without the desired attribute) behaves as if it had the default as the value of its attribute. For example:

```
if first_animal.sound == second_animal.sound:
```

can become:

```
if getattr(first_animal, 'sound', None) == getattr(second_animal, 'sound', None):
```

I don't actually recommend this, as it silently ignores errors. In real code, I'd almost always let the `AttributeError` propagate; there is no reasonable scenario in which I'd consider `None` an acceptable stand-in for "something" where "something" has specific behaviors or attributes; if the caller is passing `None`, that's almost certainly an error that should not be silently ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I think first you have to understand what's the meaning if one of the objects is None. There are basically three scenarios:

1. One or both objects are None
2. One or both objects does not have `sound` attribute
3. Both have `sound` attribute

For #1, I'm assuming it should throw an error as there is really no comparison. What your code does is print "Yes they do" if both objects are None.

For #2, you can use what ShadowRanger suggests, If both objects have `None` as `sound` property, and your think it is a normal behavior, then use ShadowRanger's solution.

For #3, just do your normal comparison

```
def do_animals_make_same_sound(first_animal, second_animal):
    if not first_animal or not second_animal:
        print("One of the objects is None")
    elif getattr(first_animal, 'sound', None) == getattr(second_animal, 'sound', None):
        print("Yes, they do!")
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a general enough pattern, I'd use a decorator to catch the None case specifically and process it. That keeps the logic out of the function. But you need to define exactly what None means here... it's a little odd that you can pass None for both, but it's not legal to just pass None for one of them. In any case, a decorator is a great way to abstract out some common logic in a clean way...

```
def NoNone(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def _no_none_func(*args, **kwargs):
        if args[0] == None and args[1] == None:
            print('Both are None')
            return 
        return f(*args)
    return _no_none_func

@NoNone
def do_animals_make_same_sound(first_animal, second_animal):
    if first_animal.sound == second_animal.sound:
        print('Yes they do!')
    else:
        print("No they don't!")
```

Comment: The problem is, lets says first_animal is defined, but second_animal is None. This technique still throws an errors, because it tried to evaluate second_animal.sound (Which will obviously throw an error if second_animal = None).

The decorator seems like what I want, but instead of  first_animal.sound == second_animal.sound throwing an error, I just want to be false and print ("No they don't")

Comment: The point is not to solve this particular problem... the point is that if you want to make your code look clearer, but there is a lot of boilerplate you need to do to validate inputs, you can put that in a separate function and add it as a decorator, and then the decorated function can just focus on what it should do with valid inputs.